# Type erased wrapper in layman terms

Tags: ios, swift, structure, swift-protocols

While researching Protocol Oriented development, I came across Apple's Swift Standard Library which shows a list of structures that referred to as  "type erased wrappers". [Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html)

What are "type erased wrappers" or what does the term "type erased" mean in layman terms?

Comment: have u tried googling? this [article](https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/) seems pretty good

Comment: Yes @Gerald I did but it seemed like the concept that was a little too advanced to understand when I found that site as well.  I'm sure it can't be that difficult to grasp with the right explanation or maybe I'll have to put more thought into to it but don't want to overthink it like I sometimes do.